# How to flip the x-axis labels only in google charts

Tags: charts, linechart, axis-labels, gchart

I'm trying to display the price of a zero-coupon bond in a graph, as the days go from 150 days to maturity to 0 days to maturity, the price rises.

When I create the graph the days on the x-axis is always displayed rising however. Is there a way to display the graph as I want to, without using negative numbers approaching zero?

Picture of what it looks like now:
[image: Current]

How I'd like it to look:
[image: Ideal]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reversing the array from the backend, while simulatneously reversing the xaxis by:

```
options={
            'title':'Orders', 
            'vAxis': {'title': "Price in percent [%]"},
            'hAxis': {
                'title': "Days to maturity [Days]",
                'direction': "-1",
                'gridlines': { 'count': '6'}
                },
           }
```